# OpenCV: Image window keeps hanging and not responding

Tags: c++, opencv

The following code draws a line connecting two points user clicks on an image:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


void onMouse(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) {
    if(evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        std::vector<cv::Point>* ptPtr = (std::vector<cv::Point>*)param;
        ptPtr->push_back(cv::Point(x,y));
    }
}

int main()

{

std::vector<Point> points;

cv::namedWindow("Output Window");

Mat frame = cv::imread("chhha.png");

cv::setMouseCallback("Output Window", onMouse, (void*)&points);
int X1=0, Y1=0, X2=0, Y2=0; 

while(1)
{
    cv::imshow("Output Window", frame);

    if (points.size() > 1) //we have 2 points
    {

        for (auto it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
        {


        }

        break;
    }
    waitKey(10);
}

//just for testing that we are getting pixel values 
X1=points[0].x; 
X2=points[1].x; 


Y1=points[0].y; 
Y2=points[1].y; 
cout<<"First and second X  coordinates are given below"<<endl;
cout<<X1<<'\t'<<X2<<endl; 

cout<<"First and second Y coordinates are given below"<<endl;
cout<<Y1<<'\t'<<Y2<<endl; 


 // Now let us draw a line on the image 
  line( frame, points[0], points[1], 'r',  2, 8 );
  cv::imshow("Output Window", frame);

  waitKey( 10 );

getch(); 

return 0;  
}
```

The problem is the program is not exiting if I close  (by clicking the cross button on the image on top right )the "Output Window", instead it hangs and says `Not responding`.

How do I remove this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your application does not exit is that you have an infinite loop, and clicking on the cross to close a window does nothing to break that loop.
One way to exit  is to test for a key being pressed, e.g.

```
    while(true)
    {
        ...
        char c = cv::waitKey(10);
        if(c == 'q')
            break;
    }
```

BTW, assuming you are on windows, if a window is destroyed `waitKey()` intercepts a [WM_DESTROY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. In this case `waitKey()` returns `message.wParam`, but the windows doco for WM_DESTROY says *This parameter is not used*. It looks like a bug to me, but it might be worth investigating whether `waitKey()` returns a consistent value when the window is closed - normally `-1` is returned if no key is pressed.